# Sorting vector of custom type with std::sort not working as expected

Tags: c++

This is my class:

```
class Animal
{
///
protected:
    const std::string name_;
}
```

This is my copy assignment operator:

```
Animal& Animal::operator=(Animal const& a)
{
    return *this;
}
```

And here my sort:

```
    std::sort(std::begin(animalVec), std::end(animalVec), [](Animal a, Animal b)
        {
            return a.getName().size() < b.getName().size(); // for some reason it doesn't sort
        }
    );
```

With:

```
std::string Animal::getName() const
{
    return name_;
}
```

The code compiles but the order of the Animal objects inside the vector is the same after the sort. Why is it not sorting?

Thanks!

Comment: Pleasse include a [mcve].

Comment: Your copy assignment operator is not doing anything. The vector is sorted correctly, but the elements weren't changed (as instructed by your assignment operator).

Comment: add the code you implemented to test the programm

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I see... So the only way I would be able to write `name_ = a.name_` inside the operator is to remove the `const` for the member class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your copy assignment is wrong. It does not modifies its left-hand side operand. You should look toward this:

```
Animal& operator=(Animal const& a)
{
    name_ = a.name_;
    return *this;
}
```

Then note:

> The generation of the implicitly-defined copy constructor is
> deprecated if T has a user-defined destructor or user-defined copy
> assignment operator. - [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor#Implicitly-defined_copy_constructor)

Accordingly, then you'd want to omit the `const` for the `name_` member. When you provide *setter* and *getter* methods, there's no need nor use in `const`ness of this data member.

```
// ...
protected:
    std::string name_;
// ...
```

Comment: `Animal& operator=(Animal const&) = default;` would be fine too :-)

Comment: I see... So the only way I would be able to write name_ = a.name_ inside the operator is to remove the const for the member class?

Comment: @Jarod42 true! But went for *(first thought)* making it all explicit :)

Comment: @AathakA: const member brings lot of "issues". As non copyable classes. Remove const from `name_` is correct.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Just out of curiosity... while copying `name_ `explicitly works well now, adding `Animal& operator=(Animal const&) = default;` causes: `error C2280: 'Animal &Animal::operator =(const Animal &)': attempting to reference a deleted function`

Comment: @AathakA I can answer correctly and thoroughly after seeing the whole class definition. For now I would assume that the class has some member whose own copy constructor is deleted or can't be accessed (e.g. a `const` member).

Comment: @rawrex @Jarod42 Yes there are other `const` members within the class. 30 minutes of debugging and asking questions saved me 2 minutes of reading the copy assignment operator documentation. Thank you all!